# How to decide the triggering order of different mouseDown function

Tags: javascript, triggers, raphael, mousedown

I have two kinds of functions which will detect the `mousedown` event and trigger some functions.

1. `window.onmousedown = function(...)`
2. `Raphael object:

     var rec = paper.rect(10,10,10,10)

     rec.mousedown(...)`

the second one is a rectangle create by **`Raphael.js`** and the function will be triggered when you click the rectangle.

I need the second one to be triggered before the first one, but  it seems that the order of triggering of the two functions is randomly decided by the browser?

Do I have any way to control it !?

thanks!!

Comment: I think I helped with the question, accept it so it won't show unanswered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### *I need the second one to be triggered before the first one*

---

Look at the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gkayG/87/)**, `mousedown` even triggers on `circle` before `window's`.

```
window.onmousedown = function()
{
    alert('Yes');
}

var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('paper'),500,400);

var circle = paper.circle(100,100,50).attr({fill:'orange', stroke:'green', 'stroke-width':3});
circle.mousedown(function() {
    alert('No');
    this.attr({fill:'green', stroke:'red', 'stroke-width':3});
});

circle.mouseout(function() {
    this.attr({fill:'orange', stroke:'green', 'stroke-width':3});
});
```

Click on the circle and see that the `alerts`. ***Good luck***